# redux-form handleSubmit not sending form data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, graphql, redux-form

`handleSubmit()` isn't sending form data. It appears the configuration object for the fields are `undefined` for some reason, even though i believe i wired up `redux-form` correctly.

LoginComponent.js

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import '../others/styles.css';

const FIELDS = {
  username: {
    type: 'input',
    label: 'Enter username'
  },
  password: {
    type: 'input',
    label: 'Enter password'
  }
};

const Login = (props) => {
  console.log('--------- props: ', props);

  const { fields: { username, password }, handleSubmit, setUsernameAndPassword } = props;

  console.log('-------- username: ', username); // PROBLEM: Returns undefined when it should return the config object for this field
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(setUsernameAndPassword.bind(this)) } id='login'>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Username</label>
          <input {...username}
            name='username' />
        </Form.Field>

....

Login.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: React.PropTypes.func,
  fields: React.PropTypes.array,
  setUsernameAndPassword: React.PropTypes.func
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'LoginForm',
    fields: Object.keys(FIELDS)
})(Login);
```

LoginContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

import Login from '../components/LoginComponent';
import LoginMutation from '../graphql/LoginMutation.gql';
import { types as typesAuth } from '../reducers/auth';

const gqlLogin = graphql( LoginMutation, {
  props: ({mutate}) => ({
    login: async function loginWithUsernameOrEmail(variables) {
      try {
        const result = await mutate({variables});
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('GQL Error: ', err);
      }
    }
  })
})(Login);

export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    setUsernameAndPassword: (data) => { // PROBLEM: Why is data empty??
      console.log('--------- data: ', data);
      dispatch({
        type: typesAuth.SET_USERNAME_PASSWORD,
        payload: {
          username: data.username,
          password: data.password
        }
      });
    }
  }),
)(gqlLogin);
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { reducer as auth } from './auth';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

export default {
  auth,
  form: formReducer
};
```

reducers.js

```
// Modules
import appReducers from '../modules/root/reducers/';
import authReducers from '../modules/auth/reducers/';

module.exports = {
  ...appReducers,
  ...authReducers
};
```

redux.js

```
// Imports
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

// Reducers
import Client from './client';
import reducers from './reducers';

const devtools = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

module.exports = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    apollo: Client.reducer()
  }),
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(Client.middleware()), devtools()
  ),
);
```

auth.js

```
// Constants
export const types = Object.freeze({
  SET_USERNAME_PASSWORD: 'AUTH/SET_USERNAME_PASSWORD'
});

// Default State
const DEF_STATE = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  username: null,
  password: null
};

export const reducer = (state = DEF_STATE, action) => {
  let newState;
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case types.SET_USERNAME_PASSWORD:
      newState = {
          ...state,
          username: action.payload.username,
          password: action.payload.password
      };
      break;
    default:
      newState = state;
  }
  return newState;
};
```

Comment: have you used button type = 'submit' in your form to submit form

Comment: I did not read through whole code, but I spotted something amiss. In your LoginComponents.js you define the propType for fileds as array, but while doing destructuring you treat fields as an object, i.e. {usrnm, pwd}. I'm guessing, [ursnm, pwd] should fix it. You can read more about array destructuring here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment . Take a look at the examples at the bottom, which mixes arrays and objects while destructuring.

Comment: @JayantPatil yes, I have `<Button type='submit'>` from `semantic-ui-react`

Comment: @AbhilashSingh I changed the PropTypes for fields like this:

`export default reduxForm({
    form: 'LoginForm',
    fields: Object.keys(FIELDS)
})(Login);`

Comment: @jenna, Yes, so indeed you are passing an array of keys. But while destructuring( the line right after console.log('----- props', props) ), you seem to treat fields as an object, when it really is an array. To destructure an array, you should use fields = [username, pwd]. See array destructuring. It's syntax is different from object destructuring.

Comment: What version of `redux-form` are you using? Because this is using the old `v5` API.

Comment: @ErikR. Code snippet is using `redux-form 6` (the latest) but i also just realized i am using old `v5` API - will look into `v5 -> v6` migration guide [here](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/MigrationGuide.md/) and try again- thanks!

Comment: @AbhilashSingh i see where youre coming from, will correct. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Field` components from `redux-form` to tie the individual inputs to the redux store ([see docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/)).

[The "Simple Form" Example](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/simple/) in the `redux-form` docs is a good demonstration of how to do this, simply import the `Field` component from `redux-form` and use it to describe your inputs. In your case it would be something like this:

```
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

const Login = (props) => {
  console.log('--------- props: ', props);

  const { handleSubmit, isLoggingIn, setUsernameAndPassword } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(setUsernameAndPassword.bind(this)) } id='login'>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>{i18n.t('auth.username')}</label>
          <Field
            component="input"
            name="username"
            placeholder={i18n.t('utils.and',{item1: i18n.t('auth.username'), item2: i18n.t('auth.email')})}
          />
        </Form.Field>

....
```

Hope this helps!